# Next Auth V4 (With Redux Toolkit): Pass in Redux Store Data to Next Auth while performing sign In

Tags: redux-toolkit, next-auth

I want to trigger the `Sign In` callback in `Next Auth` along with the redux store data. How can I access the store within my nextAuth sign In the callback, here's what I want to do:

```
async signIn({ user, account, reduxStore }) {
       const {geoLocation} = reduxStore.geoData;
      // pushGeoDataToBQ(geoLocation); Pushes the Data to a database and not needed to be async as it can run in background and user gets their active session
      return true;
    }
```

I want to somehow access my reduxStore variable inside the `signIn` block.

Comment: have you find any method?